# Windows 10 Hosts file alias not working with file share

Tags: windows, network-share, hosts-file

I am working on a project that requires that I have an alias in my hosts file that maps \\share to localhost. I added this line "127.0.0.1             localhost share" to my hosts file, and when I ping share, I get a response from localhost so I know that the alias is working. I have some locally shared folders that I can access through the Windows File Explorer when I access \\localhost\dir1, but when I type \\share\dir1, I get a prompt asking for me to enter network credentials. None of my network credentials work, and I am unable to access \\share. I did some research and determined that I can go into *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings* and disable password requirements, although I am on a domain that has restricted this option. Is there any other way that I can access *\\share\dir1* without requiring a username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a result of SMB using NETBIOS; it listens with an SNP of IP and FQDN. Your alias is essentially unknown to SMB.

You could try either 1) using `netdom` to add an alternate name, or 2) disable NETBIOS over TCP, which forces SMB direct hosting

Additional reading: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3181029/smb-file-server-share-access-is-unsuccessful-through-dns-cname-alias

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/204279/direct-hosting-of-smb-over-tcp-ip

Answer (score 0):

The line you added to the hosts file is not in the correct format. The hosts file contains some examples to follow. The pound symbol (#) indicates that the rest of the line is a comment, so be sure that yours does *not* begin with that symbol. Based on your description, your modification of the file should look like this (with my own comment added):

```
127.0.0.1    share    # make "\\share" resolve to this computer
```

Give that a try and see if it works. If not, there may be some other issue at play.